# Joining too many tables makes Postgres query extremely slow

Tags: postgresql, join, query-optimization

I've been trying to optimize this simple query on Postgres 12 that joins several tables to a base relation. They each have 1-to-1 relation and have anywhere from 10 thousand to 10 million rowss.

```sql
   SELECT *
     FROM base
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = base.t1_id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = base.t2_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = base.t3_id
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.id = base.t4_id
LEFT JOIN t5 ON t5.id = base.t5_id
LEFT JOIN t6 ON t6.id = base.t6_id
LEFT JOIN t7 ON t7.id = base.t7_id
LEFT JOIN t8 ON t8.id = base.t8_id
LEFT JOIN t9 ON t9.id = base.t9_id
```

*(the actual relations are a bit more complicated than this, but for demonstration purposes this is fine)*

I noticed that the query is still very slow when I only do `SELECT base.id` which seems odd, because then query planner should know that the joins are unnecessary and shouldn't affect the performance.

Then I noticed that 8 seems to be some kind of magic number. If I remove any single one of the joins, the query time goes from 500ms to 1ms.  With EXPLAIN I was able to see that Postgres is doing index only scans when joining 8 tables, but with 9 tables it starts doing sequential scans.

That's even when I only do `SELECT base.id` so somehow the amount of tables is tripping up the query planner.

Answer (score 4):

We finally found out that there is indeed a configuration setting in postgres called `join_collapse_limit`, which is set to 8 by default.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html

> The planner will rewrite explicit JOIN constructs (except FULL JOINs) into lists of FROM items whenever a list of no more than this many items would result. Smaller values reduce planning time but might yield inferior query plans. By default, this variable is set the same as from_collapse_limit, which is appropriate for most uses. Setting it to 1 prevents any reordering of explicit JOINs. Thus, the explicit join order specified in the query will be the actual order in which the relations are joined. Because the query planner does not always choose the optimal join order, advanced users can elect to temporarily set this variable to 1, and then specify the join order they desire explicitly.

After reading [this article](https://www.aha.io/engineering/articles/optimizing-with-the-postgresql-deterministic-query-planner) we decided to increase the limit, along with other values such as `from_collapse_limit` and `geco_threshold`. Beware that query planning time increases exponentially with the amount of joins, so the limit is there for a reason and should not be increased carelessly.